# Save HTML as an image

Tags: javascript, html, image

Is there any way I could turn HTML into an image?

Let's say I made a barcode with HTML and CSS, is there a way I could save it as an image using JavaScript?

**For example:** Save anything inside #saveImage as an image.

```
<div id="saveImage">Save this text as an image</div>
```

Comment: Good thing you searched, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156

Answer (score 1):

You can render that HTML onto a `<canvas>` and then use `canvas.toDataURL` to get an image. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas